# Woocommerce extensions in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-ecommerce

I currently have a Wordpress site hosted on my own servers with Woocommerce installed.

I would like to be able to sell carpet on this site by the meter with decimals. For example, the customer would enter "3.5" meters into an input field which would calculate the price.

https://woocommerce.com/products/measurement-price-calculator/

It looks like this extension will do exactly this but I just wanted to make sure that Woocommerce extensions would work on my Wordpress site.

Is this correct?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

As long as your site is up to date with WordPress and WooCommerce versions, then you should be able to install and use the WooCommerce extensions.

WooCommerce is maintained by Automattic who are the main developers and maintainers of WordPress so you should also get reliable support if you find yourself struggling. The main challenge I always have with WooCommerce plugins is configuring them so that they work exactly as I want them to work!

They state they have a 30 day money back guarantee and they have certainly refunded me in the past without argument.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It should because of Woocommerce's unified compatibility to it's extensions.

No worries.